# Integration of react-native with existing ios app metro config error

Tags: ios, react-native, config, bundle, preact-cli

As an ios Developer i am learning react-native with my new macbook Air. I want to add existing ios App to react-native. I did this with the help of react-native website. But every time it shows error as no metro found and gives error code 1 message.

[here is the website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps)

here is the error message

[image]

i think its configuration issue with network or other config on my new mac